# Find last items on each row

Tags: javascript

How to find the last items on each row? Each row has 4 columns and each row has `border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;`. Now, I would like the border to be removed on the last items of the row and add a class instead.

Here's my markup.

```html
<div class="product-wrapper">
  <div class="product-item">Product 1</div>
  <div class="product-item">Product 2</div>
  <div class="product-item">Product 3</div>
  <div class="product-item">Product 4</div>
  <div class="product-item">Product 5</div>
  <div class="product-item">Product 6</div>
  <div class="product-item">Product 7</div>
  <div class="product-item">Product 8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use pure CSS along with the `:not` and `:last-child` pseudoselectors like this?

```css
.product-item:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-item">Product 1</div>
    <div class="product-item">Product 2</div>
    <div class="product-item">Product 3</div>
    <div class="product-item">Product 4</div>
    <div class="product-item">Product 5</div>
    <div class="product-item">Product 6</div>
    <div class="product-item">Product 7</div>
    <div class="product-item">Product 8</div>
</div>
```

Also of note: Your `Product 2` div is missing a closing tag.

Comment: Well, what I mean is the last items of the row, not just the last-child. Eg. There are 4 rows and each rows has 4 columns, then the border of the column will be removed on the last row. Did I explained it well?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Maximillian that CSS is the way to go, but with JS the following would work:

```
var last = document.querySelector('.product-item:last-child');
last.className = last.className + " someOtherclass";
last.setAttribute('style', 'border-width:0;');
```

ref: https://jsfiddle.net/8y4kvm51/1/